# Geany c++ tag file for code completion

Tags: c++, geany

I am using an external c++ library. The header files are located in different folders like this

```
libDependencies
--dependencyA
  --A1.1
   --some header files
  --A1.2
    --another subdirectory
      --some header files
--dependencyB
  --and just like A

librarySource
--subdir
  --some header files
--some header files
```

I've learned that in order to have code completion in geany, tag files are needed. How can I make a tag file based on the above structure?

Answer (score 2):

```
geany -Pg ~/.config/geany/tags/yourproject.cpp.tags \
    `find libDependencies librarySource -type f -iname *.h`
```

I'm assuming you have `find` or (on Windows) some suitable alternative that can list files recursively, also that your header files are named with `.h` at the end.